# optimize jquery while referencing specific classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/kking/Q7tdW/24/). I'm using it to lay the ground work for a lot of projects I need to create.

I use to make these in Flash with ActionScript 3. The goal is that the player is presented with a randomized bunch of options (in my fiddle, this is represented by the blue boxes with numbers in them) and they have to drag and drop those into the correct spot. There's only one possible answer for each box.

While I have the basic functionality down, there is a lot of repeated code. I would like to make it so that I do not need individualized bits of JavaScript for each target. In AS3, you would do this with an array of the target names, a `for` loop applying the droppable function, and an `if` statement asking if the class of the dropped box is `==` to the name of the target `+` the word `'target'`. So `answer1` would drop into `answer1target`.

I tried to replicate that function in JavaScript and ran into trouble. Here's the repeated code in question:

```
$("#answer1target").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.draggable.attr("id") == 'answer1') {
            ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
            ui.draggable.position({
                of: $(this),
                my: 'center',
                at: 'center'
            });
            ui.draggable.removeClass('card');
            ui.draggable.addClass('cardCorrect');
            ui.draggable('disable');
        }
    }
});
```

I feel like the answer lies in rewriting line 3 (12 on the fiddle).. but I'm at a loss as to what to do.

My end goal is to reuse this script over and over with different amounts of cards and targets in each game. Ideally all I'd have to change in the JavaScript is some arrays and adding the individual divs in the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went and modified your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7tdW/25/) to be a bit more object-oriented.

Pretty much what I did was I condensed your individual components into single multi-object functions by selecting things by class instead of by ID, meaning your entire code has been reduced to

```
$('.card').draggable({revert:true});
$('.target').droppable({
  drop: function (event, ui) {
    // $(this).attr('id').substr(0,7) is equal to "answer1", "answer2", etc.
    if (ui.draggable.attr('id') == $(this).attr('id').substr(0,7)) {
      ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',false);
      ui.draggable.position({
        of:$(this),
        my:'center',
        at:'center'
      });
      ui.draggable.removeClass('card');
      ui.draggable.addClass('cardCorrect');
      ui.draggable('disable');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: FWIW I'd factor out the repeated deferencing of `ui.dragabble` and probably also employ jQuery chaining.

Comment: also `$(this).attr('id') === this.id`

Comment: @Alnitak There are a lot of optimizations that could be made to the code, but I didn't want to change too much and have it become unrecognizable.